# Tencent NCNN detect function on android modification

Tags: android, neural-network, java-native-interface

The application I use (https://github.com/dangbo/ncnn-mobile.git) use a native library that gives out inference result as a tag. I need it to give me a float array from which it knows the tag. The array is already implemented in the C++ files, but changing them does not effect the application itself. I would not mind if the array was written into a string, I just need the numbers in a readable format. However, the method is native and thus I do not know how to modify this behavior.

I use the newest versions of Android Studio and NCNN. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use ndk-build on the jni folder for building.